# Show a Fixed DIV when Form is changed and hide it when Form is Saved

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with an HTML FORM to add/edit/delete Project Task rows.  They are saved to a Database.

As this page can be very long/tall, right now there is a `SAVE` button at the top and bottom of page that uses AJAX to save all changes.

To make things easier, for the user to make a `SAVE` I am wanting to show a FIXED DIV across the top of the screen with a SAVE button.

This FIXED DIV should only show up when there are `Un-Saved changes`.  So when the page load you do not see this right away until you make a change on the page. At that point it comes into view.

Clicking the AJAX Save button saves the Task records to Database and then the Fixed DIV/SAVE Button will go hidden again until another Change is detected.

Right now I have this like 90% working.

I have JavaScript which has EVENTS which call my `showTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar() Function` which is shown below when:

- Text Input is changed
- Textarea changed
- Selection dropdown changed
- Button Clicked to Add a New Task Row
- Button Clicked to Delete Task Row/record

So as you see I have the code in place to Detect a `CHANGE` on the page.  This then Triggers my Function which makes my Fixed DIV with Save button come into view.

Now once you click the Save button I saved the Data using AJAX and then call my `hideTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar() Function` which is also shown below.

This makes the Fixed DIV with Save button go back to being Hidden with it's CSS `display: none` property set.

Up until this point everything described above works as expected, except in my `showTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar() Function` I added some code to make the Fixed DIV only show when you are scrolled down the screen at least `100px` so that it is not shown at the very top of screen right now.

This scroll trigger part also works fine.

The problem is, once you make a save and `hideTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar()` is called, it Hides the Fixed DIV but as soon as you scroll at all again, it keeps showing back up, even though no new CHANGES have been made to the Data on screen.

Just looking at the code below, can someone tell me what I am missing?  When my `hideTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar()` Function is called and the DIV is hidden, it should Re-set the process until another Change on page is made but I must be missing something because as soon as it goes hidden a single px scroll up or down triggers it back into view again

**UPDATE**
It seems like when my `hideTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar()` Function is Called, I need to somehow kill this Event `$(window).scroll(function()` until the `showTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar()` Function is called again, is that even possible though?

I realize a JSFiddle page might be helpful, I will work on setting one up if there isn't a simple solution posted soon.  I held off as my page is really complex and i'll have to dumb it down a lot to get a Fiddle working for the demo

```
// When there are Un-Saved changes on the Task Edit view, show a Fixed Header DIV with a SAVE Button
function showTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar(){
  if ($('#task-edit-unsaved-header-bar').length > 0) {
    var unSavedChangesHeaderBar = $('#task-edit-unsaved-header-bar');
    var fixmeTop = 100;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
        unSavedChangesHeaderBar.css({
            display: 'block',
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '10'
        });
      }
    });
  }
}



// When there are Un-Saved changes on the Task Edit view, show a Fixed Header DIV with a SAVE Button
function hideTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar(){
  if ($('#task-edit-unsaved-header-bar').length > 0) {
    var unSavedChangesHeaderBar = $('#task-edit-unsaved-header-bar');
    unSavedChangesHeaderBar.css({
        display: 'none'
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You bound an event in your function

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
```

So after that this code will always fire on scroll. If you call `showTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar` it will even bind the handler multiple times, making it fire multiple times.

#### Solution

You have to unbind this event handler when not needed anymore. Even better would be to put it somewhere outside and just switch a flag variable in your functions so that your scroll handler knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
.hide-me { display: none !important; }
```

For `hideTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar` method call `addClass('hide-me')` and in `showTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar` call `removeClass('hide-me')`

Now the scroll event won't override display to 'block'.